# javascript error 'function not defined' with html onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

The goal is when someone clicks the button element the closeModal() function is triggered and changes the display css property to 'none.' But I keep getting the error that the function set in the onclick is not defined. The javascript is above the html in the file.

Code is below.

Javascript

```
function closeModal() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
    $( modal ).css('display', 'none');
  }
```

HTML

```
<div id="modal" style="display:block;">
    <button onclick="closeModal();" id="begin">Let's get started!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The function needs to be defined in the global namespace. Otherwise, this works. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sssk29ny/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try a better and cleaner code without using JQuery

HTML:

```
<div id="modal" style="display:block;">
     <button id="begin">Let's get started!</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var btn = document.getElementById("begin");
    var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
    btn.onclick = function () {
         modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

no matter where to write your script

good luck

Comment: tried your code but there was still no response from the modal and no output from the console. thoughts on what might be blocking it?

Comment: if your testing code on jsFiddle , dont write first and last line (window.onload = ...)

Comment: here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzn0cqwa/)

Comment: Thanks, I used part of your solution to help get the answer, btw the big hold up was template inheritance system had multiple script tags embedded in the block.